# How to loop through third variable?

Tags: r, loops

I have adapted the codes below which I referred from https://statsandr.com/blog/how-to-do-a-t-test-or-anova-for-many-variables-at-once-in-r-and-communicate-the-results-in-a-better-way/#to-go-even-further into my dataset:

```
Day<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
Group<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")
Rain<-c(4,4,6,5,3,4,5,5,3,6,6,6,5,3,3,3,2,5,2)
UV<-c(6,6,7,8,5,6,5,6,6,6,7,7,8,8,5,6,8,5,7)

dat<-data.frame(Day,Group,Rain,UV)
x <- which(names(dat) == "Group") 
y <- which(names(dat) == "Rain"
           | names(dat) == "UV") 
method1 <- "kruskal.test" 
method2 <- "wilcox.test" 
my_comparisons <- list(c("A", "B"), c("A", "C"), c("B", "C")) # comparisons for post-hoc test

library(ggpubr)
for (i in y) {
  for (j in x) {
      p <- ggboxplot(dat,
                   x = colnames(dat[j]), y = colnames(dat[i]),
                   color = colnames(dat[j]),
                   legend = "none",
                   palette = "npg",
                   add = "jitter"
    )
    print(
      p + stat_compare_means(aes(label = paste0(..method.., ", p-value = ", ..p.format..)),
                             method = method1, label.y = max(dat[, i], na.rm = TRUE)
      )
      + stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, method = method2, label = "p.format") 
    )
  }
}
```

How do I further repeat this function through different "Day"? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to give a sample of your expected result while you tell us more about what you really want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to see the results for each day, right? You can add a third loop like this:

```r
for (h in unique(dat$Day)) {
  for (i in y) {
    for (j in x) {
        dat_tmp <- dat[dat$Day == h,] # create a subset of the data for each day
        p <- ggboxplot(dat_tmp,
                     x = colnames(dat_tmp[j]), y = colnames(dat_tmp[i]),
                     color = colnames(dat_tmp[j]),
                     legend = "none",
                     palette = "npg",
                     add = "jitter"
      )
      print(
        p + stat_compare_means(aes(label = paste0(..method.., ", p-value = ", ..p.format..)),
                               method = method1, label.y = max(dat_tmp[, i], na.rm = TRUE)
        )
        + stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons, method = method2, label = "p.format") 
      )
    }
  }
}
```

I added a third loop to your code and created `dat_tmp` inside the loop, which becomes the dataset that you use for the analyses of each day.